# Find: вывести файлы постранично

Tags: ssh, linux

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите можно ли в SSH, т.е. линуксе **командой find** выводить файлы постранично, если их много получается и все не видно?

Comment: less никто не отменял. Но это вопрос на [другой формум](http://admin.hashcode.ru/)

Comment: less просматривает файлы так же как и more мне нужен список файлов.

Comment: вот после этого давай правильные ответы...

Comment: @KoVadim: сослался на вас.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find . -name mask | less`

Идеология Unix-утилит состоит в том, что каждая обладает небольшой, чётко очерченной функциональностью, и пользователь может легко их комбинировать.

---

Основано на комментарии [[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)